# How to address underdispersion in a GLMM

Tags: r, generalized-linear-model, glmm, underdispersion

I've read a few entries about underdispersion in count or binomial data, relating to poisson and binomial probability distributions. However, I haven't been able to find any information about gaussian distributions with underdispersed data.

I am currently analysing the average annual change in population size (λ). I have used other metrics of change in population size, but there are reasons I have decided to move forward using average-λ. Below is the distribution of average-λ values.

[image]

When I start building a GLMM, I typically start with a GLM and slowly increase the complexity until I get to the GLMM, just so I can see where the problems arise.

Thus, using the formula:

`glm(formula = avg_lamda ~ Total_Threats, family = "gaussian", data = x5yr_data)`

Output below:

```
Deviance Residuals: 
      Min         1Q     Median         3Q        Max  
-0.200553  -0.019402   0.001415   0.021470   0.205119  

Coefficients:
                Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)     0.003944   0.002927   1.348 0.178310    
Total_Threats1 -0.021170   0.005910  -3.582 0.000372 ***
Total_Threats2 -0.021339   0.005861  -3.641 0.000299 ***
Total_Threats3 -0.012737   0.006340  -2.009 0.045053 *  
---
Signif. codes:  0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1

(Dispersion parameter for gaussian family taken to be 0.002372469)

Null deviance: 1.3082  on 533  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance: 1.2574  on 530  degrees of freedom
AIC: -1706

Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 2
```

My question is how would I transform the data average-λ values so that my dispersion becomes more acceptable?

I will also be using this data in much more complex models testing threat interaction so I will need to fix this before I get to what I am suspecting will be much more complex models.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1):

I do not understand why you believe there is anything to fix. The dispersion of a Gaussian GLM is simply the sum of squares divided by the residual degrees of freedom (see `help("summary.glm")`). As long as it is not in a range hinting at numerical problems or a perfect fit, any value is acceptable. The dispersion is used by `summary.glm` to derive the standard errors.

Comment: Thank you. I guess I have some more reading to do. During my undergrad I was originally told that deviance should roughly equal degrees of freedom, and that was an indication of under- or over-dispersion should the deviance be lower or higher respectively.

Comment: @Miles https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overdispersion#Normal_distribution